# ListView with LINQ Datasource insert template

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview

It seems like this should be straightforward but I'm boggling.  I've got my listview all setup and bound to my LINQ datasource.  The source is dependent on a dropdown list which decides which branch information to show in the listview.  My edit template works fine but my insert template won't work because it wants the branch ID which I want to get from the dropdownlist outside the listview but I don't know how to both bind that value and set it in my template.  It looks like this:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
      <td>
         <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
               Text="Insert" />
     </td>
      <td>
       <asp:TextBox ID="RechargeRateTextBox" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Bind("RechargeRate") %>' />
         </td>
              <td>
       <asp:Calendar SelectedDate='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' ID="Calendar1"  runat="server"></asp:Calendar>                                    
       </td>
           </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

I need to get a label in there that binds to the value of a databound asp dropdownlist outside of the listview so that the insert will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with this, thanks twanfosson.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Values["BranchID"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the OnSelectedIndexChanged (with AutoPostBack=True) callback for the DropDownList to manually set the values in the ListView to the defaults for that branch when the value of the DropDownList changes.

```
protected void BranchDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    RechargeRateTextBox.Text = BranchManager.GetRechargeRate( ddl.SelectedValue );
}
```

Wrap the whole thing up in an UpdatePanel and it can all happen via AJAX.