# Inserting with asp:ListView inside asp:FormView

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-3.5

I have a asp:listview which uses the SelectedValue of the FormView.

I have editing working with the listview fine, and insert will insert a record but it doesnt insert the SelectedValue of the parent FormView...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this

```
   protected void ProposalAddressListView_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Values[" My FormView Selected Value "] = MyFormView.DataKey.Value;
    }
```

**Update:**
Just found similar question, [ListView with LINQ Datasource insert template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212257/listview-with-linq-datasource-insert-template)